# How to POST form-data from React App to the backend using express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, backend

I have two classes:

1. Row (Child Class)
2. mySpreadsheet (Parent Class)

I am trying to do something like this:

Row:

```
class Row extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, ref) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedFile: null}
    this.handleUpload = this.handleUpload.bind(this);
  }

//This handleUpload is being called by the parent class of this Row class through ref.
  handleUpload(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.uploadInput.files[0]);
    data.append('filename', this.fileName.value);
    data.append('comment',this.comment.value);
    data.append('id', this.fileName.id);

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/upload', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    }).then((response) => {
      response.json().then((body) => {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: `http://localhost:8000/${body.file}` });
      });
    });
  }


  rowCreator() {
    let row = []
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      row.push(
        <td>
          <div>
            <input type="file" name={`file${this.props.id*10 + i}`} id={this.props.id*10 + 1} ref={(ref) => { this.uploadInput = ref; }}/>
            <input type="text" name={`fileName ${this.props.id*10 + i}`} ref={(ref) => { this.fileName = ref; }}  placeholder="Name the file with extension"/>
            <input type="text" ref={(ref) => { this.comment = ref; }} placeholder="Comment"/>
          </div>
        </td>
      )
    }
    return row
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td class="align-middle ">
          <div class="cell">
            <input type="text" placeholder={this.props.id + 1} />
          </div>
        </td>
        {this.rowCreator()}
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

and in mySpreadsheet I am creating each row in a table using `Row` class as follows:

```
            <tbody id="tbody">
              {this.state.data.map(id => (
                <Row id={id} ref={this.rowRef} />
              ))}
            </tbody>
```

I am using the `handleUpload()` function from the Row (child) by using rowRef:

`this.rowRef = React.createRef();`

```
upload(ev) {
   this.rowRef.current.handleUpload(ev);
}
```

```
<button onClick={this.upload}>
   Upload Files
</button>
```

But I am getting error (500) while doing a POST request through my website. Is it because of the `ref` I am using in `Row` such as `uploadInput`, for appending data in `handleUpload`? Is there any way to make a unique `ref` for all the cells in my table? Or can I use something else like `id` or `name` which I have made uniquely for all different cells using `this.props.id*10 + i` for each iteration, i while making columns for one row?

Answer (score 0):

You can create refs for mapped elements and put it in an array based on their indexes or ids.

```
// constructor state part
constructor() {
  this.refs = [];
}

// render part
{this.state.data.map(id => (
   return <Row id={id} ref={itemRef => this.refs[id] = itemRef} />
))}
```

And in my opinion, you should hold the values instead of the components itself in an array.

Id must be unique and if the map parameter is an object, you should use a unique property instead of the key which comes with map. If you use keys, React will not keep track of your component while you' re updating your state.